# How to insert new user in MariaDb/Mysql through a script?

Tags: 16.10

I have a script that install softwares in a new linux OS 16.10.

Let's say the file is called insert_app.txt.

I call this script like this:

```
# source  insert_app.txt.
```

Then the softwares are installed in a non interactive mode.

This is a portion that installs MariaDb

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server
```

That works good.
After install the database I need to create users and set privileges, like this:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'psswordUser1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user1'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

To do this I need to wait all softwares to be installed, then enter in the database like mysql -uroot -pPassword, then I run the previous command to create the users.

My question is:

Is there a way to put these commands in the same pipeline?
I mean, like this:

```
....

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server
mysql -uroot -pPsswrd
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'psswordUser1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user1'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

...
COntinue install the softwares...
```

It is not working.

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it on 16.04 or 16.10 since:

- mariaDB after installation, if you have not configured anything else it only grants access to root. So you would need to use `sudo` to run it. With this I mean (Assuming the password is 'x'):

  ```
  sudo mysql -uroot -px
  ```

  Instead of

  ```
  mysql -uroot -px
  ```

Now to run the whole line you would do the following. In my case I am creating a user called 'cyrex' with a password 'x':

```
 sudo mysql -uroot -px -e "CREATE USER 'cyrex'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'x'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'cyrex@localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

or without the User and Password parameters:

```
 sudo mysql -e "CREATE USER 'cyrex'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'x'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'cyrex@localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

After doing this, you can test by doing the following without the sudo part:

```
mysql -ucyrex -px
```

and it will work. I have provided an image so you can see the confusion since I am used to MySQL working without having to do this, but with MariaDB it changes slightly.

[image]

You can also change the password and some options by running

`mysql_secure_installation` or `mysql_setpermission` which can help in configuring the default settings.

Comment: in fact we dont even need -uUser and -pOasswrd. MariaDb install a Root user without the need a password.. All that you need  is to call mysql (to get acess to mariaDb.  This is what I did. `sudo mysql  -e "CREATE USER 'aaaa'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'aaaa'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;CREATE USER 'bbbb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'bbbb'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;select Host,User,Password from mysql.user;"`

Comment: @zwitterion - That's just beautiful. Thank you let me put it in the answer. Still seeing differences between MariaDB and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

try the `-e` parameter of mysql client:

```
mysql -uroot -pPsswrd -e "CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'psswordUser1';"
mysql -uroot -pPsswrd -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user1'@'localhost';"
mysql -uroot -pPsswrd -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

this would work even with one command:

```
mysql -uroot -pPsswrd -e "CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'psswordUser1'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user1'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```